# How to design an object model to generate a specific JSON string when serialized?

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I need to post this JSON String to a server:

```
{
   "content-spec":"urn:spec://bosch.com/cindy/measurement-message#v2",
   "device":{
      "deviceID":"1de09010-ec04-11e7-bd8a-525400ed1935"

   },
   "measurements":[
      {
         "ts":"2017-07-25T15:40:00.000+02:00",
         "series":{
            "$_time":[
               0
            ],
            "BasY":[
               1.5
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I have the following result at the moment:

```
 {
  "contentSpec": "urn:spec://bosch.com/cindy/measurement-message#v2",
  "device": {
    "deviceID": "1de09010-ec04-11e7-bd8a-525400ed1935"
  },
  "measurements": {
    "ts": "2018-01-01T21:11:42.0519229+01:00",
    "series": {
      "$_time": 10212,
      "value": 1.4
    }
  }
}
```

Note that several properties that should be arrays (marked with [] in the JSON) are simple objects.  How can I make these become arrays?

This is my code:

```
Public Function createJSONString(jContent As Dictionary(Of String, String)) As String

    Dim tmpDate As DateTime = New DateTime(Now.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc.Local)
    Dim timestamp As String = tmpDate.ToString("o") '2009-06-15T13:45:30.0000000Z
    Dim makeJSON As JSONHandling = New JSONHandling

    makeJSON.contentSpec = "urn:spec://bosch.com/cindy/measurement-message#v2"
    makeJSON.device.deviceID = jContent("deviceID")
    makeJSON.measurements.ts = timestamp
    makeJSON.measurements.series.mtime = "10212"
    makeJSON.measurements.series.value = 1.4


    Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(makeJSON).Replace("mtime", "$_time")
    '"{""content-spec"":""urn:spec://bosch.com/cindy/measurement-message#v2"", ""device"":{ ""deviceID"":""" & jContent.Item(0) & """ }, ""measurements"":[{""ts"":""" & timestamp & """, ""series"":{""$_time"":[0], ""PickY"":[" & jContent.Item(3) & "]}}]}"

End Function
```

And my models are as follows:

```
Public Class JSONHandling
    Public contentSpec As String
    Public device As JSONHandlingDevice = New JSONHandlingDevice
    Public measurements As JSONHandlingMeasurements = New JSONHandlingMeasurements
End Class

Public Class JSONHandlingMeasurements
    Public ts As String
    Public series As JSONHandlingSeries = New JSONHandlingSeries
End Class

Public Class JSONHandlingSeries
    Public mtime As Integer
    Public value As Double
End Class
```

**Update:**
What i have to do when i want do have more then one measurement?
Such like this:

```
{
  "content-spec": "urn:spec://bosch.com/cindy/measurement-message#v2",
  "device": {
    "deviceID": "1de09010-ec04-11e7-bd8a-525400ed1935"
  },
  "measurements": [
    {
      "ts": "2018-01-01T21:24:46.8354066+01:00",
      "series": {
        "$_time": [
          0
        ],
        "PickY": [
          37.4
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "ts": "2018-01-01T21:24:46.8354066+01:00",
      "series": {
        "$_time": [
          0
        ],
        "PickZ": [
          92
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "ts": "2018-01-01T21:24:46.8354066+01:00",
      "series": {
        "$_time": [
          0
        ],
        "PickC": [
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Use collection of measurements in `JSONHandling` class. `Public Property measurements As List(Of JSONHandlingMeasurements)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following types can be used to generate the JSON you need:

```
Public Class JSONHandling
    <JsonProperty("content-spec")> _
    Public Property contentSpec As String
    Public Property device As JSONHandlingDevice = New JSONHandlingDevice
    Public Property measurements As List(Of JSONHandlingMeasurement) = New List(Of JSONHandlingMeasurement)()
End Class

Public Class JSONHandlingMeasurement
    Public Property ts As String
    Public Property series As JSONHandlingSeries = new JSONHandlingSeries()
End Class

Public Class JSONHandlingDevice
    Public Property deviceID As String
End Class

Public Class JSONHandlingSeries
    <JsonProperty("$_time")> _
    Public Property TimeList As List(Of Integer) = new List(Of Integer)()

    Public Property BasY As List(Of Double) = new List(Of Double)()
End Class
```

You can initialize them as follows:

```
Public Function createJSONString(jContent As Dictionary(Of String, String)) As String

    Dim timestamp As String = "2017-07-25T15:40:00.000+02:00"

    Dim makeJSON As JSONHandling = New JSONHandling With
    {
        .contentSpec = "urn:spec://bosch.com/cindy/measurement-message#v2",
        .device = new JSONHandlingDevice With { .deviceID = jContent("deviceID") },
        .measurements = New List(Of JSONHandlingMeasurement)() From 
        {
            new JSONHandlingMeasurement With
            {
                .ts = timestamp,
                .series = new JSONHandlingSeries() With
                {
                    .BasY = new List(Of Double)() From { 1.5 },
                    .TimeList = new List(Of Integer)() From { 0 }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(makeJSON, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented)
End Function
```

Notes:

- The value for the `"measurements"` property is a [JSON](http://www.json.org/) **array** -- an ordered collection of that begins with `[` (left bracket), ends with `]` (right bracket) and whose values are separated by `,` (comma).  As explained in the [Json.NET docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationguide.htm#Lists) an array must be serialized from a .Net collection such as a `List(Of T)`, a `T()` array, or some other type implementing `IEnumerable(Of T)` for item type `T`.  Thus e.g. your `measurements` property needs to become a `List(Of JSONHandlingMeasurement)`.
- You have multiple JSON properties (`"$_time"` and `"content-spec"`) whose names are invalid VB.NET identifiers.  In such cases you can add the [`<JsonProperty("Desired Name")>`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) attribute to the member to override the name used when serializing to JSON.
- I am initializing `makeJSON` using [object initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/how-to-declare-an-object-by-using-an-object-initializer) and [collection initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/collection-initializers/) syntax.

Sample working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3VzTeC).

Comment: a short question. What i have to do when i want to have a second Measurement for BasX?

Comment: @SteffenRössler - I would need to see a [mcve] -- i.e. the JSON you wish to deserialize -- to help.